# Haproxy can load socket.http.module 'socket.http' not found

Tags: lua, haproxy

i already  install luasocket

```
Lua 5.3.1  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require("socket.http")
table: 0x9b2d80
>



debian:/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket# ll
total 56
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10640 Dec 22 17:47 ftp.lua
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3698 Dec 22 17:47 headers.lua
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13216 Dec 22 17:47 http.lua
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8074 Dec 22 17:47 smtp.lua
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3766 Dec 22 17:47 tp.lua
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11105 Dec 22 17:47 url.lua
```

in Haproxy Lua code:

```
local http = require("socket.http")
```

When i request web,

```
runtime error: /etc/haproxy/waf/lib.lua:7: module 'socket.http' not found:#012#011no field package.preload['socket.http']#012#011no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket/http.lua'#012#011no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket/http/init.lua'#012#011no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/http.lua'#012#011no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/http/init.lua'#012#011no file '/usr/share/lua/5.3/socket/http.lua'#012#011no file '/usr/share/lua/5.3/socket/http/init.lua'#012#011no file './socket/http.lua'#012#011no file './socket/http/init.lua'#012#011no file '/etc/haproxy/waf/socket/http.lua'#012#011no file '/etc/haproxy/waf/socket/http.lua'#012#011no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket/http.so'#012#011no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.3/socket/http.so'#012#011no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.3/socket/http.so'#012#011no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so'#012#011no file './socket/http.so'#012#011no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/socket.so'#012#011no file '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.3/socket.so'#012#011no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.3/socket.so'#012#011no file '/usr/lo
```

who can help me. thx

Comment: and i can't open file use Map.new,  give me error is: failed to open pattern file </etc/haproxy/ip.map>..   debian:/etc/haproxy/# ll
total 36
-rw-r--r-- 1 root www-data 1691 Dec 27 16:10 base64.lua
-rw-r--r-- 1 root www-data   50 Dec 27 16:10 ip.map

Comment: if you have something you want to add to your question, put it into your question (edit). don't use comments for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer cannot find the required files.

https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html

> To determine its path, require first checks the global variable
>   LUA_PATH. If the value of LUA_PATH is a string, that string is the
>   path. Otherwise, require checks the environment variable LUA_PATH.
>   Finally, if both checks fail, require uses a fixed path (typically
>   "?;?.lua", although it is easy to change that when you compile Lua).

The content of LUA_PATH will be copied into package.path. So either add the location of that module to the system variable befor running Lua or add it to package.path befor require.

Comment: /usr/local/share/lua/5.3/socket/http.lua is exists. There is something wrong with the installation?

Comment: and i can require in lua interaction. but in haproxy , is can't